# Print issue of the SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have a problem about that I will get reverse sequence message if the stored procedure called from linked server. I'm much appreciated if anyone know the root cause or provide a solution. Thanks in advance.

This is my test code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    PRINT '1'
    PRINT '2'
    PRINT '3'
END
```

Calling it like this:

```
EXEC [dbo].[TestSP] (call by local)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

It will show output with reverse order if executed by another linked server.

For example,

```
EXEC [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX].[dbo].[TestSP]
```

Output:

```
3
2
1
```

Comment: First, I doubt this is true. Second, `PRINT` isn't meant to return information, just debug messages. Those messages are typically batched and delivered to the client when the message buffer is full, or when a command completes, precisely because they aren't meant to return data and shouldn't interfere with/delay the data

Comment: What is the actual stored procedure? Are the `PRINT` statements executed in a loop? Was the loop order reversed? Most importantly, why does this matter? These are just informational messages, not data

Comment: I have a C# form application will execute the several stored procedures periodically.  I want to log the trace of the stored procedure every time by using InfoMessage(SqlInfoMessageEventArgs). It will let me can debug conveniently if it executed failed one day.

Comment: Not really. This does mean that your stored procedure is overcomplicated though. Instead of introducing a serious delay, simplify the code

Comment: Besides, if you want to debug a stored procedure, you can actually debug it. Or use the SQL Server Profiler or Extended Events to capture the actual commands that were executed.

Comment: I agree up to a point. Most of the stored procedures will handle the sync process between many servers. There are many unexpected situations can interrupt the script, like connection, length of columns/variables, schema, etc.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:  I think it's true because the same thing happened to someone in my team.  I've found this post because I was Googling for exactly those symptoms: PRINT statements in correct order in a stored procedure run locally, but in reverse order if run through a linked server.  This in a very simple stored procedure which is just doing an upsert (written as separate UPDATE and INSERT statements, with some guard clauses to start with to validate parameter values).  No loops or anything fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print is a debug command not a functionnal one. If you want to have a consistant order of the sequencement, you must use the RAISERROR at level 10 with the keyword NOWAIT.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestSP]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    RAISERROR('1', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    RAISERROR('2', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    RAISERROR('3', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
END
```